# Scala convert a BigDecimal column to compute Math.Sqrt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdecimal

I need to compute a square root on a BigDecimal column in my dataframe.

I have tried things like:

- sqrt(col("myCol").doubleValue())
- sqrt(cast(col("myCol"),DoubleType)

But without success.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be having a syntax issue with casting. Try this:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("sqrtCol", sqrt(col("myCol").cast(DoubleType)))
```

But from what I've tried, I think `sqrt` also works on decimal type columns, without the need for any casting.

Comment: @MatthieuK if the answer is helpful, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking the tick button, thanks!